# R: Parsing multiple values into a single field

Tags: r

I have multi-class classification dataset with data saved in the form.

[number, ..., number],number,number... ,number \n

The numbers inside brackets are the labels and have varying length. Numbers after are features with fixed length $n$. How to parse this into a R table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There probably is some perfect way to load everything in one fell swoop but since it sounds like you need a quick-and-dirty solution, you could try something along the lines of:

```
library(stringi)

df <- read.table(my.table, header=FALSE, sep=']', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
vals <- stri_split_coll(df$V2, pattern=',', simplify=TRUE, omit_empty = TRUE)
vals <- data.frame(apply(vals, 2, as.numeric))

labels <- stri_replace(df$V1, '', fixed = '[')
rownames(vals) <- labels
```

Does this get the job done for you?

[Note: If your data has a header then just add the argument "**skip=1**" to `read.table` and either add the columns manually or run the function again (with "**nrows=1**"), etc.]

Comment: Yep, quick and dirty is fine. Getting vals and labels out fine all that is needed. Can't assign rownames(vals) <- labels, since there is requirement for rownames to be unique. Got my data tho, accepted. Thank you!